# ComboBox is displaying System.Data.DataRowView no matter what is selected. ItemTemplate Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ComboBox that needs to display multiple fields in it's drop down. but only wants to store one. Right now it works to display multiple fields. but no matter what I select, the value shown in the textbox is "System.Data.DataRowView". Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Tbl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  x:Name="Supplier"
  SelectedValuePath="Name"
  SelectedValue="Name"
  IsEditable="True" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}"
    DataContext="{Binding parties}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SupplierChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}: {2}">
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="Funds"/>
                        <Binding Path="Terms"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay`and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect.

Comment: did you set displaymember value ?

Comment: you can't have both DisplayMemberPath and itemtemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here :http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/wpf-editable-combobox-with-datatemplate.html

The solution was to set TextSearch.TextPath. In my case, it was

```
TextSearch.TextPath="Name"
```

Updating my original code (unnecessary parts removed for brevity), the working version is here

```
<ComboBox 
  x:Name="Supplier"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Tbl}"
  SelectedValuePath="Name"
  SelectedValue="Name"
  IsEditable="True" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}"
  TextSearch.TextPath="Name"
  DataContext="{Binding parties}">
```

Hope this helps people out there!

Comment: This answer isn't clear and will be useless if that website ever goes down. You should really [edit] and add just the ComboBox definition with the solution applied. That'll help you get past the man.

Comment: let's see if that's true.

Comment: @Will I lost points for trying to help /posting my answer. lol

Comment: Let's see if that's true